# How can I use Inheritance to catch multiple exceptions of different types and display the stack trace showing their relationship?

Tags: java

I'm asked to Use inheritance to create an exception superclass
(called ExceptionA) and exception subclasses ExceptionB and ExceptionC, where ExceptionB inherits
from ExceptionA and ExceptionC inherits from ExceptionB. Write a program to demonstrate
that the catch block for type ExceptionA catches exceptions of types ExceptionB and ExceptionC.

the output should look like this[image]

So I start by making those classes and establishing their relationship

```
public class ExceptionA {
    public void ErrorMsg() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Exception A: Throwing Exception A");
    }
}
```

```
public class ExceptionB extends ExceptionA{
    public void ErrorMsg() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Exception B: Throwing Exception B");
    }
}
```

```
public class ExceptionC extends ExceptionB{
    public void ErrorMsg() throws NullPointerException {
        System.out.println("Exception C: Throwing Exception C");
    }
}
```

Here's the main method

```
public class ExceptionTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ExceptionC c = new ExceptionC();
        ExceptionB b = new ExceptionB();
        ExceptionA a = new ExceptionA();
    
        try {
            a.ErrorMsg();
            b.ErrorMsg();
            c.ErrorMsg();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            StackTraceElement stackTraceElement[] = e.getStackTrace();
            for(int i = 0; i < stackTraceElement.length; i++) {
                System.err.println(stackTraceElement[i].getFileName() + ":"
                + stackTraceElement[i].getLineNumber() + ">>"
                + stackTraceElement[i].getMethodName() + "()");
            }
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Q: How can I avoid creating an instance of each exception object? Like I did, and which I also just manually called their error msg? Is there a way to have the error caught in the try block and have it past to the superclass resulting in each subclass firing their specific error method?

Just so you know this is for my Java class that I've been dodging, really because I'm lazy and I thought my basic JS knowledge could help me scrape by. So Everything I've pieced together from people of YT.

Comment: I don't think you should be looking to _avoid_ creating an instance of each exception type: I think that's the whole point.  You also need to `throw` those exception objects in order to know whether the `catch` works or not.  And the demonstration would be much more convincing if the `catch` clause were `catch (ExceptionA exa) {...}, so that you can show that all three are caught by that one `catch`.

Comment: @KevinAnderson Thanks for the reply! Forgive me though, can you expand more on `throw`-ing those Exception Objects. All I know about throw is that it returns the Exception to the `Catch` but I don't know what that looks like in code. And your suggestion to change the catch clause to `(ExceptionA e) {...}` makes sense cause I had thought that the exception needed to be passed to the parent class then like run the  constructor, printing the error, get overloaded to B then to C showing the stacktrace....Anyway back to trying it, which I did, and I'm getting an error saying

Comment: "No exception of type ExceptionA can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable"

Comment: `ExceptionA` needs to extend `Exception` (which, itself, is a subclass of `Throwable`).